# How to enable AngularJS validation for button that is outside of form?

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, angularjs-validation

I am new to angular, I was struck to trigger a **form validation** with the button outside the form. I have **two buttons** one inside form, which works and one outside, I want the **outside button** to do the **same task** as **inside one**

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <p>Username:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>Email:
        <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid || 
                                          myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
    </p>
</form>
```

MY PLUNKER 
http://plnkr.co/edit/QObTwo1FcX4pC4f9sAL6?p=preview

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

To make it work you need to move your button into Angular's scope, for that you need to move `ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl"` from your `<form>` tag to `<body>` tag, also you need to make sure `<button>` tag has same `ng-disabled` attribute as the button inside.

**Full demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl">
    <h2>Validation Example</h2>
    <form name="myForm" novalidate>
    
        <p>Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
        </span>
        </p>
    
        <p>Email:<br>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
        </span>
        </p>
    
        <p>
            <input type="submit"
                   ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||
                                myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
        </p>
    
    </form>
    
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||
                         myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
        another outside button to trigger form  
    </button>
    
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.user = 'John Doe';
            $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```